# How to get the value of an object using for of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I'm trying to use [`normalize-url`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize-url) in my code here:

The `socialfields` is an object I converted to an array using the `for...of` loop. The value of the socialfields keys are URL to social medias
e.g:

```
{
  youtube: 'youtube.com/peoray',
  facebook: 'facebook.com/peoray',
  twitter: 'twitter.com/peoray',
}
```

So I'm trying use `normalize-url` on the links. But it's not working. The error I'm getting is that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Here is the code:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(socialfields)) {
    if (value.length > 0)
        socialfields[key] = normalize(value, {
            forceHttps: true
        });
}
```

Comment: apparently one of the social media urls is `null`. It means the `value` will be `null` and `null.length` is an Error.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean it will be null. Sorry for my noob question

Comment: Are you sure that's the actual value of `socialfields`? It seems like it should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do `if (value.length > 0)` - the following should be fine: `if (value)` or if you really wanted `if (value && value.length > 0)` - this is happening because the `.length` property does not exist on a null object/variable.

Comment: Yes, that's the actual value.

Comment: print the `socialfields` object right before the for loop. My guess is that you have an entry like this `pinterest: null`

Comment: @LEQADA you're correct. I'm not adding all the fields I'm getting from the request. In my case, I'm not adding Instagram and LinkedIn

Comment: @MattOestreich code solved the issue although I'm open to a more elegant and clean solution if any

Comment: Is `if (value)` not clean enough? That's all you need....

Comment: Thanks. If you want, you can add it as an answer and I'll choose it @MattOestreich

Comment: Sounds good @Peoray - I just added an answer :) Cheers! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have to do `if (value.length > 0)` - the following should be fine: `if (value)` or if you really wanted `if (value && value.length > 0)` - this is happening because the `.length` property does not exist on a null object/variable.

This is all you should have to do:

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(socialfields)) {
  if (value) socialfields[key] = normalize(value, { forceHttps: true });
}
```

If you wanted to get 'fancy' you could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).. I still think the `if (value) ...` is the best way to go about it.

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(socialfields)) {
  value ? socialfields[key] = normalize(value, { forceHttps: true }) : '';
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the second option. VSCode threw an error `';' expected.ts(1005)`

Comment: Yea I removed it, I forgot you couldn't use it before an assignment.